# Hi , I want to remove the empty cell from my list before I process it in python

Tags: arrays, list, csv, whitespace

Example:

```
address= [' ', 'LUT NAME/Register Address', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '17', '18', '23', '24', '34', '36', '37', '38']
```

I want it convert to:

```
address=['LUT NAME/Register Address', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '17', '18', '23', '24', '34', '36', '37', '38']
```

or

```
address=['LUT NAME/Register Address', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
to address = ['LUT NAME/Register Address']
```

To give more information, i generated it from a csv file to process it like an array and write to a text file but i want to remove unwanted white space so that i can do some math.
I am using windows shell python 3.5 version. I have tried split , strip, join. but doesn't work, I get errors like no attributes found.

Help will be appreciated, new to python.

Thanks

Comment: I was able to use del function over a range to do it.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

You could just loop through and remove white spaces like this

```
address = [item for item in address if item.strip()]
```

You could try this

```
address=['LUT NAME/Register Address', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']

address_string = ''.join(address)

address_string = address_string.strip()

address_string.split(',')
```

This will return you

```
['LUT NAME/Register Address']
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i get following output when i do this, it removes the empty cell but its only a string and not a comma separated list anymore.                                                                                            address = [' ', 'LUT NAME/Register Address', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '17', '18', '23', '24', '34', '36', '37', '38']
address_string = LUT NAME/Register Address 0 1 2 3 4 5 10 11 12 13 14 15 17 18 23 24 34 36 37 38

Comment: @RF_Sat Updated my answer. You can just loop through and eliminate empty values like this `[item for item in address if item.strip()]`